# Sending web users in to the correct page

Tags: php, html, validation, methods, input

does anyone care to explain why this php method always sends user to granted.htm. When the website user enters the correct word, in this case: Shadow, the php sends the user to granted.htm. If anything else is entered into the website textfield the php will send them to denied.htm. Both pages have been uploaded to web space. Thanks.

```
<?php
$check = "Shadow";
if($check === "Shadow"){
    echo 'Perfect Match!';
    header('Location: granted.htm');
}
else {
    echo 'Wrong Password!';
    header('Location: denied.htm');
}
exit();
?>
```

Comment: beacuse you have set `$check = "Shadow";`, remove it

Comment: as @RamSharma has said; `$check = "Shadow"; if($check === "Shadow")...` will always return true

Comment: How are you sending the value from the textfield to this php file? I would expect to see something like `$check = $_POST["Shadow"];`. As it stands this code is meaningless

Comment: @Steve - ahh I have been trying to learn a little bit of relevant php by taking apart a contact form script im php, I removed those parts because I thought that 'Post' must be relevant onlu to email, thanks.  Il give it another look at. Meaningless because I dont realy understand what meaningful :)

Comment: No problem. And whilst dissecting code can be a good way to learn, a decent book is usually the best starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the part where you submit the passwort?

```
<?php
$check = $_GET['check'];
if($check === "Shadow"){
    echo 'Perfect Match!';
    header('Location: granted.htm');
}
else {
    echo 'Wrong Password!';
    header('Location: denied.htm');
}
exit();
?>
```

Now you simply access the page like this:

example.com/thisfile.php?check=Shadow

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
$check = "Shadow";
```

before the IF condition

This sets $check to "shadow" and IF condition always becomes TRUE

Comment: Just made this chang... removing first $check statement and now It will not let me access the granted page with the correct password. It now only sends me to denied.htm?

Comment: Set $check = "shadow" only when user's password is correct. Wherever you are checking that the password is correct or not, just set $check = "shadow" there.

Comment: As an example because php is relatively new to me, you said"only set $check when users pass is correct, Ive been led to believe thos method does check if tje string is correct? So who do I check whether a users string matches the string I set?

Answer (score 0):

You already set **$check = "Shadow";**.So, **if($check === "Shadow")** always return true and it always sends the user to the **granted.htm**.

**Remove :**

```
$check = "Shadow";
```

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded this code to my server and gave it a spin.
It works just fine when you change `$check` to something different than "Shadow"

What you're doing here is going to granted.htm when `$check` equals "Shadow".
So when I changed `$check` it's value to something else I was redirected to denied.htm.

There is nothing wrong with the script, it does exactly what it should do.

Give it a try, **change `$check` to something else** and see the magic happen. :)